# AngularJS passing lastTime to a service to display only recent posts

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am not sure if I am going about this the right way but what I want to achieve is a Twitter feed like effect.

I have a Statuses page, on the first page load it will get all the statuses and after then it will only display the updates on the page.

I have a service that calls the API:

```
emp.services.SocialService = ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/feed').then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    this.getStatuses = function () {
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getStatuses: this.getStatuses
    };

}];
```

And my controller:

```
emp.controllers.StatusesController = ['SocialService', '$scope', '$interval',  function(SocialService, $scope, $interval) {

    $scope.statuses = [];
    $scope.lastTime = 0;

    $scope.refreshStatuses = function() {

        var statuses = SocialService.getStatuses();

        statuses.then(function(data) {

            $scope.statuses = data.data;

            for(id in $scope.statuses) {

                item = $scope.statuses[id];

            }

        });
    };

    $scope.periodicRefresh = function() {
        $scope.refreshStatuses();
        $interval($scope.periodicRefresh, dataInterval, true);
    };

    $scope.periodicRefresh();



}];
```

Could somebody please take a look at this and let me know how I can improve it, push the updates only to the view. I assume that I also need to somehow pass the lastTime through to the API URL so that I can use that to only grab any updates, then somehow push those through to the view?

Any help, tutorials etc greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a mayor issue with your SocialService. You make an http only at service intialization and return always the same promise in the getStatuses function. A promise can only be resolve once.

Comment: At every http service request store the lastUpdate time in the service and then add this value as a parameter at every update request.

Comment: Thanks, Micheal, I am a complete noob when it comes to these new fangled front end frameworks, would you mind providing a code example of what is the correct way when it comes to my http request and also the passing of the time etc? Hopefully i can learn from that :)

Comment: @TheRabbitFactory you should try something by yourself, and ask if it doesn't work, with the code you tried.

Comment: Here's a little sample / hope this helps. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xYNPvn8mrID0IcHpSZGl?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building services, try and keep all "service-related" functionality inside the service scope. This will help reduce your controller footprint in the long run. In addition, it's important to understand that "promises" are used throughout the angular framework by default. In this case the $http service already returns promises.

Please review your service below:

```
emp.services.SocialService = ['$http', function ($http) {

    var totalRefreshCount = 10,
        currentRefreshCount = 0;

    function getStatuses() {
        return $http.get('/api/feed');
    };

    function updateTotalRefreshCount() {
        currentRefreshCount = currentRefreshCount + 1;
        return currentRefreshCount;
    }

    function shouldRunAgain() {
        return totalRefreshCount >= currentRefreshCount;
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        currentRefreshCount = 0;
        return;
    }

    return {
        getStatuses: getStatuses,
        shouldRunAgain: shouldRunAgain,
        updateTotalRefreshCount: updateTotalRefreshCount,
        resetCounter: resetCounter
    };

}];
```

Notice how "getStatuses" just returns the $http method? Notice how I've started to encapsulate all "polling" and/or "recursion" logic here as well. This refers back to my original statement, "Try and keep all service-related code in our service scope".

Please review your controller below:

```
emp.controllers.StatusesController = ['SocialService', '$scope', '$timeout',  function(SocialService, $scope, $timeout) {

    var dataInterval = 1 // in seconds;

    $scope.statuses = [];

    $scope.refreshStatuses = function() {

        SocialService.getStatuses().then(function(data) {

            $scope.statuses = data.data;

        });

    };

    $scope.periodicRefresh = function() {

        $scope.refreshStatuses();

        if (!SocialService.shouldRunAgain())
            return;

        $timeout(function(){

            $scope.periodicRefresh();

            SocialService.updateTotalRefreshCount();

        }, dataInterval * 1000);

    };

    SocialService.resetCounter();
    $scope.periodicRefresh();

}];
```

There were some variables that your code was using that I didn't understand. For example, "dataInterval" and "item". They were used but never defined...

"refreshStatuses" is the same code. It looks nearly identical to what you had before. It even works with the "then" method. Again, due to $http already returning promises.

For your "polling", instead of creating an interval instance, do a timeout instead. This is a more appropriate approach to recursion as you will not be creating any unnecessary interval loops.

Finally, all the logic for the recursion (ig "how many times it should run" and "when should it stop") is held in the service. This is because it pertains to the service.

You could take this further by moving the "periodic" refresh to the service as well. Again, mostly because it is ONLY service logic.

The result:

Your api/feed will be fetched every 1 second for the course of 10 attempts.

Please review the areas where there are undefined variables.

Angular will trigger it's digest cycle. Your statuses will be updated every time the refresh runs.

---

**EDIT: Adding time stamp for API**

```
emp.services.SocialService = ['$http', function ($http) {

    var totalRefreshCount = 10,
        currentRefreshCount = 0,
        timeStamp = null;

    function getStatuses() {

        // generate query param
        var query = timeStamp === null ? "" : "?ts=" + timeStamp.toJSON();

        // update/create time stamp
        timeStamp = new Date();

        return $http.get('/api/feed' + query);
    }

    function updateTotalRefreshCount() {
        currentRefreshCount = currentRefreshCount + 1;
        return currentRefreshCount;
    }

    function shouldRunAgain() {

        if (totalRefreshCount >= currentRefreshCount) {
            updateTotalRefreshCount();
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    function resetCounter() {
        currentRefreshCount = 0;
        timeStamp = null;
        return;
    }

    return {
        getStatuses: getStatuses,
        shouldRunAgain: shouldRunAgain,
        resetCounter: resetCounter
    };

}];
```

"getStatuses" will contain a time stamp query parameter whenever a new request is made.

Our controller only changes slightly:

```
emp.controllers.StatusesController = ['SocialService', '$scope', '$timeout',  function(SocialService, $scope, $timeout) {

    var dataInterval = 1 // in seconds;

    $scope.statuses = [];

    $scope.refreshStatuses = function() {

        SocialService.getStatuses().then(function(data) {

            // appends new array to existing.
            $scope.statuses.push.apply($scope.statuses, data.data);

        });

    };

    $scope.periodicRefresh = function() {

        $scope.refreshStatuses();

        if (!SocialService.shouldRunAgain())
            return;

        $timeout($scope.periodicRefresh(), dataInterval * 1000);

    };

    SocialService.resetCounter();
    $scope.periodicRefresh();


}];
```

These small changes will not solve your ALL your issues. You will need to rely on your server for returning results that have been created ONLY AFTER the time stamp.

Comment: This is perfect and works really, really well! However, I can see this getting a little slow as there could be hundreds of statuses and every time it refreshes it is getting them all. Now, is there a way of modifying the code above to pass perhaps a lastId or lastTime to the API, the api will then only retrieve records that have been created after this time and Angular will 'push' them to the $scope.statuses array?

Comment: I hope that makes sense? Think of it as a Twitter style feed, but instead of clicking X New Updates link, it automatically pulls new ones and sticks them at the top of the page :)

Comment: Mate, that edit is perfect, does exactly what I need! I can see where I went wrong now, I did try this before hand but where you have .push.apply I had not added the .apply. Thanks for the help!